# The logo of visual studio code and sublime text 3 is not showing well

Tags: installation, visual-studio-code, sublime-text-3

Ok so I downloaded both VsCode and sublime text 3 but after some time the logo of `code.exe` is not showing well. The logo's color changed into a white color. But when I changed the path of visual studio code then it worked well. So I fully deleted VsCode and downloaded it again, it worked fine! And now same problem appearing with sublime text 3 what to do now ?? I dont want to fully delete sublime text 3 always so can someone tell me a good way to fix the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Seem that you missing a lot of information, like what is your OS ? what version ? Doe's other icons is look OK ?
Based on popular community, I assume you using Windows 10, if so:
Right click the icon and click Properties, in the window you will have button 'Change Icon..' - click, and new windows will be open, then find the 'exe' of sublime text, and select it, all the available icons will be there, just select the one you wish for, and click 'OK'.

Comment: I am using windows 7, Can ya tell me a gpod way for windows 7 please =)

Comment: And also icon is not only white there is a blue color at center of the icon. We can see the icon in java bin so many times :)

Comment: Try this steps: https://imgur.com/a/w2VaW9C